# "Failed to instantiate module 'app' due to" in angular and mean stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

So I recently played around mean stack with express node jade and angular; and actually I think there is a problem in jade somehow; and I apologise for complexity, but I really can not figure it out, hoping for some different view from the outside; so here is the case:

the message itself:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/$injector/nomod?p0=app
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:63:12
```

ok, We go to 63 of angular js: `return new ErrorConstructor(message);` -> well, it tells nothing, but some idea that the problem is really hiding in nowhere;

```
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1747:17
```

go to this 1747 either: `throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled " +` -> again nothing to understand here; so what do you think of it?

```
    at ensure (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1671:38)
    at module (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1745:14)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:4041:22
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:322:20)
    at loadModules (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:4025:5)
    at createInjector (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:3951:11)
    at doBootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1434:20)
    at bootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1455:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%….googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.3%2Fangular.js%3A1455%3A12)
```

File structure:

```
_client
   vendor //for bower installations
   styles 
   application
      angularCore.js

_server
   views
      core.jade
      states
         home.html

server.js
```

>

```
server.js :


==stuff===

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '_server/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '_client/')));

app.get('/states/:Path', function(req, res) {
   res.render('states/' + res.params.Path + '.html');
 });

 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
   res.render('core');
   console.log(res);
 });

==stuff==
```

_server/views/core.jade :

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    link(rel="shortcut icon", href="favicon.ico", type="image/x-icon")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="styles/bootstrap.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="vendor/toastr/toastr.min.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="styles/core.css")

  body(ng-app='app')
    div(ng-view)
     h1 Some text

    script(type='text/javascript', src='vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular-route.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular-resource.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='./application/angularCore.js')
```

_client/application/angularCore.js :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/states/home',
```

so, coz of a problem states/home.html not loaded in network tab as i see;

```
      controller: 'controllerMain'
    });
  }


app.controller('controllerMain', function($scope) {
  $scope.myVar = "Hello peolm";
});
```

_server/views/states/home.html:

```
<h1>That's the state home</h1>
<h2>{{myVar}}</h2>
```

So the logic of app is go to localhost:3030 to '/', then due to angular's

```
when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/states/home',
```

and express's

```
app.get('/states/:Path', function(req, res) {
   res.render('states/' + res.params.Path);
 });
```

receive home.html and we're good, but home.html not rendered, not even loaded, and I don't know because of what;
All of the files downloaded by browser, by client, except 'home.html';

So that's the main question: all are downloaded, my why cant it find 'app' module?

Comment: is your `angularCore.js` file in the `_client/app/` directory or in `/application/`?  The error is clear that it cannot load the app module, which seems to indicate that the script isn't loading correctly. it is unusual to see `./` in the src path.

Comment: oh, that was my bad, it is actually in 'application';

Comment: the src for your javascript file should be relative to the root of the application, not relative to the jade file, so `./` doesn't seem to make sense.  are you able to download the js file if you browse to `http://youserver.com/application/angularCore.js`? If so, I suspect removing the `.` would fix the script loading.

Comment: in the Developer Console on the network tab, you should be able to see the file that is coming back 404, causing the module to not be available.

Comment: './' do not making changes at all, I was trying all the variations to find a solution;
All of the files downloaded by browser, by client, except 'home.html'; So that's the main question: all are downloaded, my why cant it find 'app' module?

Comment: Yeah, they're all 200, I checked again

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, the Angular code is referring to a template in `/states/home`, but you have Express rendering that URL?  All Angular templates should be served up via your static assets (think of them just the same as you would the javascript code or CSS).

Comment: @dylants, yes, express should render them and send this particular file; in this case home.jade or home.html (neither is working properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hilarious.

The problem was here: `$locationProvider.html5mode(true);` well, there is no html5mode, but html5**M**ode;

Answer (score 1):

On first glance I think your are missing .html here

```
app.get('/states/:Path', function(req, res) { 
   res.render('states/' + res.params.Path + '.html');
});
```

Comment: I added, but it wasn't a solution :(
thanks for an answer, unfortunately I lack the reputation to vote answers

Comment: Did you add your view engine as app.set('view engine', 'jade'); then you do not need this .html but rename home.html to home.jade

Comment: yeah, that was done;
but then I realised may be jade was the problem, so I switched to html to render angular's part of a deal